# Entity Framework Core 3.0 performance impact for including collection navigation properties (cartesian explosion)

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, .net-core

We're facing a major performance problem after upgrading EF Core 2.2 to EF Core 3.0. Imagine a simple data model with a single collection navigation property and hundreds of fields (the reality looks even darker):

```
public class Item
{
  [Key]
  public int ItemID {get;set;}

  public ICollection<AddInfo> AddInfos {get;set;}
  ...  // consisting of another 100+ properties!
}
```

and

```
public class AddInfo
{
  [Key]
  public int AddInfoID {get;set;}
  public int? ItemID {get;set;}
  public string SomePayload {get;set;}
}
```

During item retrieval, we're querying as followed:

```
...
var myQueryable = this._context.Items.Include(i => i.AddInfos).Where(**some filter**);
... // moar filters
var result = myQueryable.ToList();
```

Straight forward, up until this point.

In EF 2.2, fetching that queryable results in two separate queries, one for `Item` and one for the `AddInfo` - level. These queries usually fetch 10.000 `items` and around 250.000 `AddInfos`.

In EF Core 3.0 however, a single query is being generated, left-joining `AddInfo` to `Item`  that on first glance appears to be the better option. Our `Item` however needs to be fetched with all 100+ fields, which is why projecting to a smaller class or anonymous type (adding a call to the .Select(...)-method) isn't feasible. Therefore, the result set has so much redundancy in it (each `Item` approx. 25 times) that the query itself takes too long to run in an acceptable time.

Does EF-Core 3.0 provide any option that would enable us to switch back to the query-behavior of the good old EF Core 2.2 times *without* extensive changes to our data model? We're already profiting from this change in other parts of the application, but not in this particular scenario.

Many thanks in advance!

**Update**

After further investigation I found that this issue is already adressed with Microsoft [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/18022) and out of the box, there seems to be no way to configure the split query execution.

Comment: Is the query over a web connection (http)?  The default headers may be different in Core 2.2 and Core 3.0 (like http version 1.0 and http version 1.1).  You may want to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and check the first request to verify the headers are the same.

Comment: Read this [warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#code-try-5). You are right the behavior is changed it is matched with the old EF 6.x behavior. What i can't understand How was EF 2.2 was translating it to just 2 queries. Do you have samples for that?.

Comment: @Eldar, thank you for providing the link. The translation to two queries was made possible, because the same filter (--> WHERE-Clause) was used to fetch data from the Item and AddInfo table, the latter of course with a join back to the item table itself. EF stitched the items and their collection navigation properties back together in memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the update of my initial question, the insights went so far as to assure myself that currenty, there is in fact no built in configuration to return to split query execution.

However, MS provided code samples on how to do this with minimal code changes (for our use case!) [here](https://gist.github.com/smitpatel/d4cb3619e5b33e8d9ea24d3f2a88333a).

We're simply removing the .Include(...) calls to collection navigation properties (1:n relations in our case, 1:1 relations are not affected!). After fetching the items, we're simply making another call using:

```
...
var myQueryable = this._context.Items.Where(**some filter**);
... // moar filters
var result = myQueryable.ToList();
...
var addInfos = myQueryable.Include(x => x.AddInfos).SelectMany(x => x.AddInfos).Select(x => new {x.ItemID, x}).ToList();
```

This fetches the collection navigation property entities and - if change tracking is enabled - automatically fills the collections on the individual items in the `result` variable.

Comment: Can you share the output (generated sql query) of the second query as well.